# How to convert only first letter uppercase without using Initcap in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to convert the first letter uppercase in Oracle SQl without using the Initcap Function?

I have the problem, that I must work with the DISTINCT keyword in SQL clause and the Initcap function doesn´t work.

Heres is my SQL example:

```
select distinct p.nr, initcap(p.firstname), initcap(p.lastname), ill.describtion
from patient p left join illness ill
  on p.id = ill.id          
where p.deleted = 0
order by p.lastname, p.firstname;
```

I get this error message: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

Comment: What's the problem with `DISTINCT`? I see no problems in `DISTINCT` with `InitCap`; can you please post your code?

Comment: I have edit my question

Comment: When SELECT DISTINCT, you can't ORDER BY columns that aren't selected.

Comment: But without initcap function it works great!

Comment: It's not InitCap, is the fact that you apply a function to the field you use for ordering; even substr or any other function will give the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `SELECT DISTINCT`, you can't `ORDER BY` columns that aren't selected. Use column aliases instead, as:

```
select distinct p.nr, initcap(p.firstname) fname, initcap(p.lastname) lname, ill.describtion
from patient p left join illness ill
  on p.id = ill.id          
where p.deleted = 0
order by lname, fname
```

Answer (score 2):

this would do it, but i think you need to post your query as there may be a better solution

```
select upper(substr(<column>,1,1)) || substr(<column>,2,9999) from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

To change `string` to `String`, you can use this:

```
SELECT
regexp_replace ('string', '[a-z]', upper (substr ('string', 1, 1)), 1, 1, 'i')
FROM dual;
```

This assumes that the first letter is the one you want to convert. It your input text starts with a number, such as `2 strings` then it won't change it to `2 Strings`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the column number instead of the name or alias:

```
select distinct p.nr, initcap(p.firstname), initcap(p.lastname), ill.describtion
from patient p left join illness ill
  on p.id = ill.id          
where p.deleted = 0
order by 3, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH inData AS
( 
  SELECT 'word1, wORD2, word3, woRD4, worD5, word6' str FROM dual
),
 inRows as
(
  SELECT 1 as tId, LEVEL as rId, trim(regexp_substr(str, '([A-Za-z0-9])+', 1, LEVEL)) as str
  FROM inData
  CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
)
SELECT tId, LISTAGG( upper(substr(str, 1, 1)) || substr(str, 2) , '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rId) AS camelCase
FROM inRows 
GROUP BY tId;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).